# How to add shape to a TextView CompoundDrawables

Tags: android

Instead of using in my layout ImageView and TextView I am now adding the image like this:

`text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, mImagesId[position], 0, 0);`

In order to add border to the ImageView I defined a shape xml that I am using as a BackgroundResource.
How can I now add the shape to the TextView image up compound ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a layered drawable that contains the shape you want + your image. See the LayerDrawable class for more info.